# print function in main wont display anything

Tags: python

I'm a bit of a noob; just wondering whats wrong here

```
__author__ = 'Ghossein'

def double(x):
    x = 0.0
    d = 0.0
    d = x + x
    return (d)

def trip_dub(x):
    t = 0.0
    t = double(x) + double(x) + double(x)
    return(t)

def main():
    result=0.0
    result = double(trip_dub(1.0))
    print(result)
```

I want to print 'result' but when i run the code nothing comes up (no errors either). If i put print(result) on it's own line then it says result is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

You never call `main`.  Normally, you'd have a:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

line at the end of the script.  The `__name__ == '__main__'` bit will be `True` only if the module is run as the main script (as opposed to being imported from another module).

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually call the function. Throw this at the end of your script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No problem! <3 (By the way: the conditional is so that you can import the functions and use them in other scrips *without* printing until you call the function.)